Alert a job if the previous 3 weeks have the same flag
I need an alert column that notifies me if the previous 3 week instances for a job have the same flag.
I have multiple run times for a job in a given week but I only care about the run time median for that week for that job to set my flag.
If a week of data is missing from a job I want to just default to using the previous weeks flag.
This will be used to help alert me if a process has shifted in run time.
Basically if I have 4 consecutive flags I want to have an alert.
Data set with columns that should be flagged (https://i.sstatic.net/V0fNvY9t.png)
I tried change flag + sum([Flag Change]) OVER (Intersect(Previous([Year & Week],3),[Job ID]))+ sum([Flag Change]) OVER (Intersect(Previous([Year & Week],2),[Job ID]))+ sum([Flag Change]) OVER (Intersect(Previous([Year & Week],1),[Job ID])) but there were 2 issues. If a week did not have data for a job it would default to null and in the earlier weeks like 20241 (Intersect(Previous([Year & Week],3) would look for week 202398 which does not exist, it should be looking for 202351
